# IOS ICViewPager's pageviewcontroller tabs with transparent color

Tags: ios

Thank you for looking at the question.I am using the open source project called ICView controller https://github.com/iltercengiz/ICViewPager I would like to ask how can i set the background color of the tabs to transparent so that the lower part of the background image in content view controller can be shown.I set all the factors to clear color in the delegate as shown below. However, the tabs' background turns into black. I have been looking for answers from web and stack but no results have been found. Can anyone give me some suggestions? Thank a lot

```
- (UIColor *)viewPager:(ViewPagerController *)viewPager colorForComponent:(ViewPagerComponent)component withDefault:(UIColor *)color {
switch (component) {
    case ViewPagerIndicator:

        return [UIColor clearColor];
        break;
     case ViewPagerContent:
        return [UIColor clearColor];
        break;

        case ViewPagerTabsView:
        return [UIColor clearColor];
        break;

}
return color;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use this code , it may help you

```
- (UIColor *)viewPager:(ViewPagerController *)viewPager colorForComponent:(ViewPagerComponent)component withDefault:(UIColor *)color {

switch (component) {
    case ViewPagerIndicator:
        return [UIColor whiteColor];
    case ViewPagerTabsView:
        return [UIColor colorWithRed:244 green:67 blue:54 alpha:0.4];
    case ViewPagerContent:
        return [UIColor whiteColor];
    default:
        return color;
}
```

}